# Inject div inbetween two divs using nth-child and .after?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, insertafter

I have a bunch of divs, which are being outputted via PHP which all contain images. I have a lone div that I want to inject after the 4th div, but I'm having issues achieving this. I am using Isotope to grid the images/divs.

An example of my jQuery:

```
$('.each-brewery-image:nth-child(4n)').after('<div>Test</div>');
```

An example of my HTML:

```
<div class="each-brewery-image">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="#">
   <span>
       <img width="700" height="524" src="01.jpg" />
   </span>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="each-brewery-image">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="#">
   <span>
       <img width="700" height="524" src="02.jpg" />
   </span>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="each-brewery-image">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="#">
   <span>
       <img width="700" height="524" src="03.jpg" />
   </span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `:eq(3)` instead of `:nth-child(4n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:nth-child(4n)` selects the 5th, 9th, 13th, etc. elements. You probably want `:eq()`:

```
$('.each-brewery-image:eq(3)').after('<div>Test</div>');
```

`:eq()` and `:nth-child()` are zero-indexed, so `:eq(0)` is the first item, `:eq(1)` is the second, etc.

Comment: `:nth-child(4n)` will select the 4th, 8th, etc elements. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LNevS/). Though `n` is zero based it doesn't work the same as `eq()`. `nth-child(4)/nth-child(4n)` selects the 4th or every 4th element while `eq(4)` [selects the 5th element](http://jsfiddle.net/dTpxR/).

Answer (score 2):

Your existing code should work, using [**nth-child(4n)**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qyBP/) - Your original code working with nth-child(4n)

---

However, if your expectation is to only append the new div after the 4th element you should use [**eq(3)**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead or you could get unexpected results.

`eq()` is `0` based so you need to use `eq(0)` for the first element and so on. So the 4th would be `eq(3)`.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLnb9/) - insert test div after 4th image using `eq(3)`

---

As per your comments even `eq()` didn't seem to work:

> This hasn't worked, unfortunately. Could it be to do with the PHP
>   generating the items first?

In general try wrapping your code into a [**document ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure the code executes only after the DOM is ready, similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.each-brewery-image:eq(3)').after('<div>Test</div>');
});
```

If your code is injecting the HTML after the DOM has been loaded through some other action you need to execute the desired code ones the elements are in the DOM to apply the changes.

---

#### Why use `eq(3)` if `nth-child(4)/nth-child(4n)` seems to work too?

---

For general completeness I thought adding this section could be useful to any future users coming across this question who might have issues using `nth-child()`.

Using `nth-child()`  will match **all** elements of the selector preceding the last element `nth-child()` is called on.

**nth-child(x) - not using `n`**

For example if you have 2 `ul` with several `li` each then `$('ul li:nth-child(2)')` will select the second element in **both** `ul`s. Which would be the same as `$('li:eq(1)', 'ul')`.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tcq4P/) - Select second element in each `ul` using `$('ul li:nth-child(2)')`
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6FA3b/) - Same result as above using `$('li:eq(1)', 'ul')`

---

**nth-child(xn) - using `n`**

Using `$('ul li:nth-child(2n)')` on the other hand will match **every** second `li` in both `ul`s. That is because `n` is used like a counter.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yCyEA/) - Select every second element in each `ul` using `$('ul li:nth-child(2n)')`

---

Comment: Thanks for comments. This hasn't worked, unfortunately. Could it be to do with the PHP generating the items first?

`foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<div class="each-brewery-image"><a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'"><span>'.wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'brewery-standard').'
</span></a></div>'; }`

Comment: In your HTML example you use only 3 images so `eq(3)` won't match anything. the last element is `eq(2)`. Off course if this is only sample HTML and you have a 4th element then try wrapping your code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){// your code here})`